# React hook destructuring returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have this hook:

```
const useGetPokemon = async (input) => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState(null);
  const [fetchError, setFetchError] = useState(null);
  const { clearErrors } = useForm();

  const fetchPokemon = async (input) => {
    input = input.toLowerCase();

    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${input}`);
      const { data } = res;

      if (data) {
        setPokemon(data);
        setFetchError(null);
        clearErrors();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setPokemon(null);
      setFetchError(error);
      // example custom error: setError("custom", { type: "manual", message: "custom name error" });
    }
  };

  return { fetchPokemon, pokemon, error: fetchError };
};
```

Which is trying to be destructured inside another component:

```
const PokemonForm = () => {
      const { fetchPokemon, pokemon, error } = useGetPokemon();
      const getPokemonDebounced = useDebounce(500, fetchPokemon);
      console.log("fetchPokemon", fetchPokemon); // undefined..?
      console.log("getPokemonDebounced", getPokemonDebounced); // empty Fn..?
```

But for some reason it returns undefined. I'm not sure why as it should be accessible as it's within scope and it's just a simple async function.

I don't think the debounce hook is problematic because this seems to work:

```
const getPokemonDebounced = useDebounce(500,() => {2});
```

Any ideas why this happens? Here's a better demo to see: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-22rlh?file=/Pokemon.js

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async method always return a Promise.
Since `useGetPokemon` is an async method, it return a Promise. And `Promise` does not contain fetchPokemon property, so the variable `fetchPokemon` is undefined.
On the other hand, hook should not be an async method.

Comment: Why should hook not be an async method? usually you write a custom hook to retrieve data from the server. Is this not recommended?

Comment: I guess React save the hook state using stack, so the order of execution is very important. React request hook must be in a functional component, and all hook must be executed in any case (The hook should not in a if statement.) and at fixed times (The hook should not in loop statement). The async method is lazy invoked, it does not meet the requirement of React.

Comment: On the other, you can use async method in the callback of `React.useEffect`.